# Legend missing when converting eps to pdf

Tags: graphics, epstopdf, ghostscript

I have a problem when importing a .eps file produced with tecplot in Texstudio with MikTeX2.9 on Windows10.

As I save the .eps file the figure is right, including the legend. When I import it in Texstudio and converts it in .pdf with graphicx and epstopdf the legend is not shown correctly.

[image: How it looks]

[image: How it sould look]

I absolutely need the highest resolution given by .eps because it is for my PhD thesis and I cannot put low resolved images. The picture is generated with Tecplot so I cannot do directly Save figure as it was done in Matlab. Any idea how should I solve the problem? I installed the latest version of Texstudio and I am desperately looking for a solution.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a short compilable TeX code using that image?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to load the `epstopdf` package; loading the `graphicx` package and running`\includegraphics[<options>]{imagefile.eps}` should work fine. If it does not, then you're probably applying some inadvertent trimming while saving the graph in .eps format in the file `imagefile.eps`.

Comment: Off-topic: Is there any way you could (a) divide the y-axis units by `10^{6}`(so that the y-axis numbers would range from `5.4` to `6.6`) and (b) change the y-axis label from `Pressure (Pa)` to `Pressure (1E6 Pa)`? That would make the y-axis much easier to read.

Comment: I also tried to remove the epstopdf package but unfortunately it does not work. The trimming is not applied since when I open the saved .eps file it shows the image correctly. I think it is a problem of the ghost script or so.

Comment: \begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{\figfolder/1L/setup/pressuresetup2.eps}
\end{figure}

Comment: Ok, I found out the problem. When exporting the file from Tecplot, I just removed the option EPS preview image setting putting it to None. Thanks a lot for your time!